# Нужна ли запятая перед союзом «и» в данном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

И всегда посещал его в разное для себя время: в первый раз у меня было отличное настроение и я просто хотел сводить в хорошее место близкого человека.

Answer (score 1):

***И всегда посещал его в разное для себя время**: в первый раз у меня было отличное настроение и я просто хотел сводить в хорошее место близкого человека.*

Запятая перед союзом И не ставится, так как два предложения, связанных союзом И, относятся к первому. Общим элементом для них является **бессоюзная связь**, обозначенная двоеточием.

Правило: Розенталь: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133

Пункт  2 (3). Перед союзами и, да (в значении и), или, либо запятая не ставится, если части сложносочиненного предложения объединены каким-либо **общим элементом.**

3. Общей может быть поясняемая двумя частями сложносочиненного предложения **третья часть,** предшествующая им и связанная с ними бессоюзной связью: Берегов не видать: их скрыла ночь и оттолкнули куда-то широкие волны разлива (М. Г.);

**Примечание по стилистике**

Как мне кажется, первое предложение лучше записать так: *И всегда посещал его **по разным для себя причинам** (поводам)*...